# What does drawing on a Goddess Wall do?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

On your way to Dungeon 4, you end up having to go back into Dungeon 1.

Just inside the entrance, a mole man gives you a hint about playing your harp near where butterflies gather.  Doing this where he's standing makes a symbol appear on the wall.

What does this symbol do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a **Goddess Wall**.  It just provides you an opportunity to get some free stuff: hearts, rupies, bombs, arrows or fairies.  You have to draw certain shapes on the wall in order to choose what you want in one stroke.  To initiate it, you need to find a wall, stand in front of it and charge for a **Skyward Strike**.

**Sheikah Stones** and other characters will give you hints at what you need to draw.

There are 5 different things you can draw that the game will recognize, otherwise you will get the default **3 hearts**.

1. > You can draw a heart to get hearts.
   >  [image: diagram 1]
2. > You can draw a rupee to get rupees.
   >  [image: diagram 2]
3. > You can draw a circle to get bombs.
   >  [image: diagram 3]
4. > You can draw an arrow to get arrows.
   >  [image: diagram 4]
5. > You can draw the Triforce to get fairies.
   >  [image: diagram 5]

Just a warning if you have a widescreen TV with widescreen settings enabled on your Wii, apparently the game doesn't compensate for the stretching that is needed to maintain the correct aspect ratio.  So when drawing on the **Goddess Walls**, I recommend you turn that off temporarily, otherwise you'll have a hard time drawing respectable lines.

Comment: As you wish; it looks ugly IMHO though.

Comment: I believe just drawing a horizontal line is close enough for #4.

Comment: Don't forget that drawing anything else gives you some hearts

Answer (score -1):

The harp can be used to find The Goddess Walls. They can be found near butterflies. Once you used the skyward strike method, you can draw things such as bombs, arrows, hearts and so forth. They're quite useful, and a lot faster. Once you know how to repeat this process in the three areas, you may have a better chance to continue in a dungeon.

Also, if this still a bit confusing, you can get more info on www.Youtube.com. Make sure you let me know on other stuff. I may know how to help you out!

Answer (score -1):

They are Goddess Walls. They are all in the three areas: faron woods, eldin volcano, and lanayru mine. You get stuffs such as bombs, arrows, hearts, rupees and fairies. Perhaps rupees aren't important, unless you need them for more adventure pouches and use them for bottles and get fairies. Sometimes you may need fairies for a tough opponent. That's when you need some hearts before you continue. Once you have enough, you may also need bombs and arrows. Please note you may need the bow first after you get the harp in order to get arrows but you can still get bombs. You can find out how to draw them from the Sheikah Stone in Skyloft. Plus you may need to be careful how you draw. For example, you wanted hearts but if the drawing looks too messy, you may end up getting bombs instead.
Like Jeff said, you can get the five drawings from his post.

Hopes this helps to anybody who is still having trouble.

Thank you for reading this post! It may be long, but i hope they still works for you guys!