# What shapes can I draw on a Goddess Wall?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does drawing on a Goddess Wall do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38360/what-does-activating-the-symbol-on-your-way-to-dungeon-4-do)

So Goddess Walls seem pretty neat - they give you free stuff if you draw on them!

...except, the game does a less than adequate job of telling you what shapes to draw.

I've been standing here with the goron in the Sealed Grounds, and though he keeps telling me to "Draw an Arrow in repose", I have no idea how to actually do that?

What shapes can you approximate on a goddess wall for phat loots? I've gotten rupees and hearts before - and from the Goron's comments, I'm assuming I can get arrows somehow too -- but is that it?

Comment: Have you tried an arrow sticking out of a knee? Oops, wrong game.

Comment: Cripes. That duplicate needs a rename. No wonder I couldn't find it.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Yeah, I was thinking the same thing, however I think his title is good if you don't know what a Goddess Wall already is.